# Uniform distribution with Random

Tags: java, random

I know if i use the Random generator from Java, generating numbers with nextInt, the numbers will be uniformly distributed. But what happens if I use 2 instances of Random, generating numbers with the both Random classes. The numbers will be uniformly distributed or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The numbers generated by each `Random` instance will be uniformly distributed, so if you combine the sequences of random numbers generated by both `Random` instances, they should be uniformly distributed too.

Note that even if the resulting distribution is uniform, you might want to pay attention to the seeds to avoid correlation between the output of the two generators. If you use the default no-arg constructor, the seeds should already be different. From the source code of `java.util.Random`:

```
private static volatile long seedUniquifier = 8682522807148012L;

public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }
```

If you are setting the seed explicitly (by using the `Random(long seed)` constructor, or calling `setSeed(long seed)`), you'll need to take care of this yourself. One possible approach is to use a random number generator to produce the seeds for all other generators.

Comment: except `volatile` is not grantee to be atomic.

Comment: @J-16: I believe it is guaranteed with the new Java memory model introduced with Java 1.5 (http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile). Anyway this is not my code; it is the internal implementation of `java.util.Random`.

Comment: Under any JMM, `long` has always been atomic regardless of whether you mark it `volatile` or not (meaning you will never see half-written values.)  What's not atomic (again regardless of `volatile`) is the read&increment&write of the long.  So it's possible for multiple threads to all read the variable as `0` (for example), all increment the value to `1`, and all write `1` back to the variable.  To ensure that the counter 100% reliably increments once per access, you need synchronization.  The classes in `java.util.concurrent.atomic` like `AtomicLong` make this easy and correct.

Comment: @Mike: Wrong. Reads and writes of non-volatile longs are **NOT** guaranteed to be atomic, and you can certainly see half-written values. This is not the case for longs marked `volatile`. See section 17.7 of the Java Language Specification (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.7). Also you can easily check this with a simple test program. Your other comment about read-modify-write cycles not happening atomically is correct, though.

Comment: @Grodriguez So you are right!  Thanks you for correcting me about the possibility of half-written values for non-volatile longs and doubles.

Comment: System.nanoTime() is monotically increasing and you are *highly* unlikely to make the call in two threads at the same nano second.

Comment: @Peter: Note that even if the two calls do not occur in the same nanosecond, there is no guarantee that System.nanoTime() will actually reflect this. From the Javadoc: "This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently values change."

Answer (score 9):

Well, if you seed both `Random` instances with the same value, you will definitely not get quality discrete uniform distribution.  Consider the most basic case, which literally prints the exact same number twice (doesn't get much less random than that ...):

```
public class RngTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random r1 = new Random(currentTime);
        Random r2 = new Random(currentTime);
        System.out.println(r1.nextInt());
        System.out.println(r2.nextInt());
    }        
}
```

But that's just a single iteration.  What happens if we start cranking up the sample size?

Here is a scatter plot of a distribution from running two same-seeded RNGs side-by-side to generate 2000 numbers total:

[image]

And here is a distribution of running a single RNG to generate 2000 numbers total:

[image]

It seems pretty clear which approach produced higher quality discrete uniform distribution over this finite set.

Now almost everyone knows that seeding two RNGs with the same seed is a bad idea if you're looking for high quality randomness.  But this case does make you stop and think: we *have* created a scenario where each RNG is independently emitting fairly high quality randomness, but when their output is combined it is notably lower in quality (less discrete.)

Comment: You answer a question with a question.

Comment: you are right, but note that even in this case, the resulting distribution **is** uniform.

Comment: @Grodriguez the plot may be misleading - remember that on the first scatter plot, each point is actually 2 points overlapping exactly.  Visually, chart 1 appears uniform just with fewer samples than chart 2.  But in fact both charts have the same number of samples -- the first less randomly placed than the second.  At least, that's how I think of it.  I wonder what the Chi Squared Test would say about the output.

Comment: Yes, I know. However the resulting distribution is still uniform.

Comment: Well, I am not a statistician.  I do not know the correct terms to describe the fact that RNG1(s1)&RNG2(s1) working in tandem produce a lower quality discrete uniform distribution than simply using RNG1(s1) alone.

Comment: @MikeClark It's not that it's less uniform, it's just a smaller sample. If you'd run the single rng with 1000 values instead of 2000 you'll get the same output.

Comment: @shinzou it is definitely less uniform if I want 2000 uniformly distributed values but 1000 of them are falling close to the other 1000 and there are gaps in-between