# List of random numbers

Tags: algorithm

I need to generate a list of numbers (about 120.) The numbers range from 1 to X (max 10), both included. The algorithm should use every number an equal amount of times, or at least try, if some numbers are used once less, that's OK.

This is the first time I have to make this kind of algorithm, I've created very simple once, but I'm stumped on how to do this. I tried googling first, though don't really know what to call this kind of algorithms, so I couldn't find anything.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create a list with all the necessary numbers, then shuffle them a-la Fisher–Yates: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Almost every language has a library function to provide pseudo-random numbers. Are you required to implement the algorithm from scratch?

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. Just go with the nextInt() function (java). It gives fairly uniform distribution of numbers just like you want.

Comment: Simply listing 1,2,3...X, 1,2,...X, 1,2 .... until you get 120 numbers meets your requirement. Most answers assume you want random numbers or distribution. Unfortunately this is impossible; a random distribution will not meet your requirement that the algorithm tries to use each number an equal number of times. You could randomly permute the sequence 1,2,3...X, 1,2,...X, 1,2 .... but that won't be a "random" sequence of numbers, as not all possible sequences are equally likely or even possible. But in terms of what you probably really want to do, its probably the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is first fill a list with the numbers you want and then shuffle that list.  One way to do this would be to add each of your numbers to the list and then repeat that process until the list has as many items as you want.  After that, randomly shuffle the list.

In pseudo-code, generating the initial list might look something like this:

```
list = []
while length(list) < N
    for i in 1, 2, ..., X
        if length(list) >= N
            break
        end if
        list.append(i)
    end for
end while
```

I leave the shuffling part as an exercise to the reader.

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments the above will always put more smaller numbers than larger numbers.  If this isn't what's desired, you could iterate over the possible numbers in a random order.  For example:

```
list = []
numbers = shuffle( [1, 2, ..., X] )
while length(list) < N
    for i in 1, 2, ..., X
        if length(list) >= N
            break
        end if
        list.append( numbers[i] )
    end for
end while
```

I think this should remove that bias.

Comment: This biases towards smaller numbers, at least on the last iteration, right? (Generating 10 numbers between 1 and 8 will always give you 2 1's and 2 2's and 1 of everything else)

Comment: Yes, it does.  It was unclear from the OP whether this mattered (they wanted an equal number of each).  If this is an issue, one option would be to iterate through the available numbers in a random order while adding them to the list.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is a `uniformly distributed` `random number` ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29)). It means that if you generate 10 numbers between 1 to 10 then there is a high probability that all the numbers 1 upto 10 are present in the list.

The Random() class in java gives a fairly uniform distribution. So just go for it. To test, just check this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   int rNum = rand.nextInt(10);
```

And see in the result whether you get all the numbers between 1 to 10.

One more similar discussion that might help: [Uniform distribution with Random class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253500/uniform-distribution-with-random)

Comment: `It means that if you generate 10 numbers between 1 to 10 then there is a high probability that all the numbers 1 upto 10 are present in the list.` This claim is wrong. the probability for all 10 numbers to be in a list of 10 is 10!/10^10~= 0.00036

Comment: Ok genius, read it correctly first! It means that: P(nextInt() will generate uniform distribution) ~ 1. The nextInt() function is specially written to create this uniform distribution. So even if the number of ways that can happen is less in the whole sample space, the probability is high. Think of a biased coin which gives more heads than tails. Will P(T) in that case be still 1/2? This is a perfect example of half baked maths! And some idiot has also agreed with you.. lol

Comment: My point is not that it is 'less then' the whole sample space. **it is MUCH less then the whole sample space**. For example, if you draw only 2 numbers with uniform distribution from U[1,2] you can get 4 lists: [1,2],[2,1],[1,1],[2,2]. Each list has the same probability to be 'selected' (1/4). So, the probability to get a list as desired is only 0.5 (`p([1,2]) + P([2,1]) = 0.5`). This is NOT high probability. It becomes worse as the list gets longer.

Comment: Here you go, I made a micro-benchmark for you, run it and check the results:   Random rand = new Random(5);
  int[] expected = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  int corrects = 0;
  for (int t = 0; t < 1000000; t++) {
   int arr[] = new int[10];

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    arr[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
   }
   Arrays.sort(arr);
   if (Arrays.equals(arr,expected)) corrects++;
  }
  System.out.println(corrects/1000000.0);
 }

Comment: The nextInt() function does not simply pick 'any' number from your [1,2],[2,1],[1,1],[2,2] sample space. So if it has already picked 1, it highly tends to pick 2 (and not 1 again) and if it has already picked 2, it highly tends to pick 1 (and not 2 again). So from the total sample space, if you run that function for lets say 1000 passes, in 990 of them (say) you'll get the [1,2], [2,1] samples, 'shifting' the probability towards a uniform distribution. The probability is biased to create a uniform distribution as output. Those are the basics of creating a random variable in programs.

Comment: the `nextInt()` function in java does not do it, as you can see in the benchmark I provided. no `nextInt()` function that I am familiar of doesn't do it actually, because it will make the list of elements dependent - which is usually not the desired result.

Comment: I do not think, that is the correct way to test it. For example: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9 is also a desirable result even if 9 is repeated (90% correct result), because we are creating a 'random' sampling which means a number may be repeated. But your program compares the whole array entirely and rejects such samples. So that is simply not acceptable. The problem is not to create a permutation of 120 numbers, rather generating 120 numbers randomly (the question says at least 'try')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46538/discussion-between-amit-and-ashis-kumar-sahoo)